# Assign to a slice of a Python list from a lambda

Tags: python, list, lambda, variable-assignment

I know that there are certain "special" methods of various objects that represent operations that would normally be performed with operators (i.e. `int.__add__` for +, `object.__eq__` for ==, etc.), and that one of them is `list.__setitem`, which can assign a value to a list element. However, I need a function that can assign a list into a slice of another list.

Basically, I'm looking for the expression equivalent of `some_list[2:4] = [2, 3]`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The line

```
some_list[2:4] = [2, 3]
```

will also call `list.__setitem__()`.  Instead of an index, it will pass a `slice` object though.  The line is equivalent to

```
some_list.__setitem__(slice(2, 4), [2, 3])
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I did not know there was a special `slice` object.

Comment: There's also operator.setitem(some_list, slice(2,4), [2, 3])

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the version of Python. For 3.2, [`__setitem__`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-container-types) does the job:

> Note Slicing is done exclusively with the following three methods. A call like
>   a[1:2] = b
>   is translated to 
>   a[slice(1, 2, None)] = b
>   and so forth. Missing slice items are always filled in with None.